# Adding a shapefile in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile

Recently I am working on a project which is based on making map for state-wise health care indicators. And I am getting the data (shapefile) from here: [link](https://static.fossee.in/mapathon/Mapathon2020_Data/)

I just downloaded the shapefile which are present in that site and then I tried to add that shapefile in QGIS software but I can't and it shows :

```
Invalid Data Source: C:\Users\sasua\Desktop\India_District_Boundary.shp
is not a valid or recognized data source
```

I am pretty sure that file is shapefile but it doesn't work. What do I have to do to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you made sure all additionally necessary files are in the same directory?

Answer (score 3):

You probably have not all necessary files in the same folder or you have diffent names for the sidecar files: see here for details about the [multifile format of Shapefiles](http://switchfromshapefile.org/#multifile). If you want to open the India shapefile, be sure you have all the following files in the same folder and don't change filenames:

```
India_Boundary.cpg
India_Boundary.dbf
India_Boundary.prj
India_Boundary.qpj
India_Boundary.shp
India_Boundary.shx
```

This is how it should look like: I downloaded the files from the link you posted, thus you see that the files are valid.
[image]